# Airpod Pro taking over Microphone Despite me Choosing my Yeti for Input

Tags: microphone, airpods

Ever since upgrading my Macbook Pro M1 (2020) to Monterey, I cannot get my Yeti to remain as the microphone consistently.

My typical scenario for meetings is to have my AirPods set as the speaker, and my Yeti set as the microphone. I've been doing this for a year now flawlessly.

Now what happens is that I set my AirPods as the speaker, my Yeti as the mic, and then I literally watch MacOS switch the mic back to AirPods within 1-2 seconds.

Here's a quick video: https://photos.app.goo.gl/kfLQnbSsxF8rdNHd8

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try setting the separate inputs and outputs with Audio MIDI Setup? Right-click on the device to chose what to set it as.

Comment: Hey @unbeatable101, thanks for the idea. I'm not familiar with this application, but oddly it doesn't appear as if I can set the Yeti as a microphone. "Use this device for sound input" is greyed out.