# AirPods Pro with other mic, possible?

Tags: iphone, facetime, microphone, airpods, call

I saw I few people claiming RØde Wireless Go mic is great. And my mom keeps complaining about FaceTime call quality while I'm using AirPods Pro, she says she can hear all kinds of noises besides my voice (that means I can't wash the dishes while talking). I replaced AirPods a while ago due to another issue, so I can say in fact after trying two different pairs still hear mom's same complain.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use another mic as sound input while on a call (on FaceTime and/or other apps) using AirPods Pro, i.e. RØde Wireless Go?

I use an iPhone 12 mini.

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: I agree that AirPods are overly sensitive to certain sounds. Have you tried turning on [voice isolation](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/change-the-audio-settings-iphb54d5dee2/ios)?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/430991/151404

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do this with an iPhone, as it doesn't have very good input device selectors. There are workarounds in macOS you can try though